# Python transform and convert yml to json

Tags: python, json, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a online liner (or two) for converting YAML file to Json and perform a simple transformation.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import yaml,json

yml="""
- AppName: Wiki-server
- InstanceType: m4.large
"""

#                 Version 1:
y = yaml.load(yml)
o=[]
for i in y:
  d={}
  d['ParameterKey']=i.keys()[0]
  d['ParameterValue']=i.values()[0]
  o.append(d)
print json.dumps(o, indent=2)
```

I got the result i needed:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterValue": "Wiki-server", 
    "ParameterKey": "AppName"
  }, 
  {
    "ParameterValue": "m4.large", 
    "ParameterKey": "InstanceType"
  }
]
```

I attempted to shrink the code and got the same results.

```
#                 Version 2:
p=("ParameterKey","ParameterValue")
o=[dict([zip(p,d.items().pop()) for d in [s] ].pop()) for s in y] 
print json.dumps(o, indent=2)

#                 Version 3:
(pk,pv)=("ParameterKey","ParameterValue")
o=[b for r in [ map(lambda (k,v): {pk:k,pv:v}, s.iteritems()) for s in y ] for b in r]
print json.dumps(o, indent=2)
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that golfing always leads to pythonic code, but here's the best I can come up with. I think that it's fairly clear what's going on while also being concise. Not a huge fan of the magic numbers in there though.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import yaml,json

yml="""
- AppName: Wiki-server
- InstanceType: m4.large
"""

y = yaml.load(yml)
d = [i.items()[0] for i in y]
d = [{'parameterKey': k_v[0], 'parameterValue': k_v[1]} for k_v in d]
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```